# Cross Database one-to-one relationships in maria db

Tags: sql, database, mariadb

In my MariaDB database server, I have a table that looks like this (output of `show create table Contracts`) in the `Contracts` database:

```
CREATE TABLE `Contracts` (
  `Id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Guid` uuid NOT NULL DEFAULT uuid(),
  `Locale` varchar(400) NOT NULL,
  `Title` varchar(400) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ImageGuid` uuid DEFAULT NULL,
  `DocumentNumber` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `UtcDate` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `IX_Contracts_Unique_Guid` (`Guid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `IX_Contracts_Unique_Title_And_UtcDate` (`Title`,`UtcDate`),
  KEY `IX_Contracts_Guid` (`Guid`),
  KEY `IX_Contracts_Locale` (`Locale`),
  CONSTRAINT `Ck_Contracts_NonEmptyGuid` CHECK (`Guid` <> '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'),
  CONSTRAINT `Ck_Contracts_NonEmptyImageGuid` CHECK (`ImageGuid` <> '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000')
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci
```

now In another database Called `Tracking` I want to have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `TruckHeadContracts` (
  `Id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Dummy` varchar(400) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci
```

Now when I run this script:

```
alter table `TruckHeadContracts`
add constraint FK_TruckHeadContracts_Id_Contracts.Contracts_Id
foreign key (`Id`)
references `Contracts.Contracts` (Id)
on update cascade
on delete cascade
```

I get this error:

```
Error in query (1103): Incorrect table name 'FK_TruckHeadContracts_Id_Contracts'
```

I want to have a one-to-one relationship between these two at the db level so that I wouldn't have to adjust my code to behave like these two are one-to-one.

What is my mistake? is it syntactical or is this just not possible to do?

Comment: Essentially a syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your alter table to this:

```
ALTER TABLE `TruckHeadContracts`
ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_TruckHeadContracts_Id_Contracts`
FOREIGN KEY (`Id`)
REFERENCES `Contracts`.`Contracts` (`Id`)
ON UPDATE CASCADE
ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

It may because constraint naming.
You can check on my fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/TJYVjBp_)